# Includepdf causes an error message from pgfplots externalization

Tags: pgfplots, pdf, pdfpages, tikz-external

I have a file `test.pdf` which I include in a document containing also an externalized pgfplots picture.

When I compile the following code, I get the error message `Sorry, the system call pdflatex ... did NOT result in a usable file`. 
In order to make my code work, I first need to remove the `includepdf` statement, compile (to create the externalized figures) and then compile again with the `includepdf` statement.

I suppose that it is a bug, or is there any possibility to solve it ?

Of course, the file `test.pdf` is totally independent from the externalized pictures from pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
 \usepgfplotslibrary[external]
 \tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

 \begin{document}
\includepdf{report_test-figure44}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xlabel=Cost,
ylabel=Error]
 \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
 (2,-2.8559703)
(3,-3.5301677)
};
\end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: I have found a hack to avoid this problem in my case : let the pdf document be full page with \AddToShipoutPicture.

Comment: Quite interestingly, if the `\includepdf` command is added *after* the externalize step has been performed, there's no error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is the option to "optimize expensive commands away" when externalizing stuff.

Since the includepdf statement is irrelevant for externalize, we could optimize it away - and your example compiled fine.

To be more precise: I moved `\usepackage{pdfpages}` *before* the externalize call and configured includepdf as "remove away":

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
 \usepgfplotslibrary[external]
 \usepackage{pdfpages}
 \tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18,optimize command away=\includepdf]

 \begin{document}
\includepdf{report_test-figure44}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
 xlabel=Cost,
ylabel=Error]
 \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
 (2,-2.8559703)
(3,-3.5301677)
};
\end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

This appears to work fine.

Comment: Isn't this a bug? Has this been reported?

Comment: I tested this with PGF v3.0.1a, and it does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mentioned in the [documentation](https://tikz.dev/library-external#sec-52.8.2).

A workaround provided which includes the `pdfpages` package in the main document but not on the externalized documents,

```latex
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\tikzifexternalizing{%
    % don't include package XYZ here
}{%
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{vmargin}
    ...
}%
```

however, a test I run in a not very clean setup still fails.

Comment: Good to link to the relevant part in the documentation. However, you should probably provide a MWE that somehow relates to the OP's code.